# How to insert 2 queries with sequence in oracle?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, sequence

I have two queries:

```
INSERT INTO CLASS
(TEACHER_ID, CLASS,)
VALUES (:i_teacher_id, :i_class)
INSERT INTO TEACHER_INFO
(TEACHER_ID, TEACHER_NAME) VALUES (:i_teacher_id, :i_teacher_name)
```

teacher_id is incremented by sequence like this: t0001, t0002, t0003 ...etc

Then I tried to do it:

```
INSERT INTO TEACHER_INFO
(TEACHER_ID, TEACHER_NAME) VALUES (teacher_seq.nextval, :i_teacher_name)
```

But sequence give me just "4" not t0004

Comment: What is `teacher_id` so that it is so incremented?  Sequences are just numbers.  There really isn't a need to use strings for such ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If teacher_id must be in this format, and must be constructed as part of the insert statement, you could do this:

```
INSERT INTO TEACHER_INFO 
(TEACHER_ID, TEACHER_NAME) 
VALUES ('t'||LPAD(teacher_seq.nextval, 4, '0'), :i_teacher_name)
```

That is, add the initial "t", then append the next sequence number after padding it out to 4 digits with zeroes.